# Even-odd consistency in R

Tags: r, statistics

I was hoping to calculate even-odd consistency in my dataset using the careless package. The code takes the following arguments:

```
evenodd(x, factors, diag = FALSE)
```

In their tutorial (https://www.ryentes.com/careless/intro.html), they have an example where they have a dataset of 10 scales that are 10 items each so their line of look looks like this:

```
evenodd(careless_dataset2, factors = rep(10,10))
```

My issue is that my dataset varies in the length of the scales. Furthermore, there are some columns throughout that I don't want to be included (e.g. random demographic questions). I tried to subset my data and just have a data frame with 1 scale that had 10 items so my subsetted data had 10 columns.

So I tried this to indicate 1 scale and 10 items:

```
evenodd(careless_dataset2, factors = rep(1,10))
```

In return, I got all NAs. I do not have any missing values. I was hoping get some help on 2 things:

1. How can I manipulate the factors argument to choose custom columns to tell R which scale is which?
2. A more statistical question, am I maybe getting NAs because my scale is too short? I was able to take the even items and the odd items and calculate a correlation by hand, so I was thinking this wouldn't be the problem, but maybe I am missing something.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got in touch with the authors of the careless package and they very kindly helped me with my problem. I wanted to post it here in case it will be helpful to anyone in the future.

1. You can use dplyr::select( to choose which columns you want to use and you specify their length in the factors argument.
2. You actually don't want to subset one scale at a time because evenodd consistency should be calculated across different scales in your entire battery. It is just important to specify in the factors argument where the cut-off are.